# Proper disposal of SqlConnection inside of using

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio

Does the `SqlConnection` get properly disposed?

```
/// <summary>
/// Executes the stored procedure using the parameters.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="storedProcedureName"></param>
/// <param name="parameters"></param>
/// <param name="timeoutValue"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public DataSet ExecuteStoredProcedure(string storedProcedureName, List<SqlParameter> parameters, int timeoutValue = 0)
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    var sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)Database.Connection;

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(storedProcedureName, sqlConnection))
    {
        //setting CommandTimeout specified value
        if (timeoutValue > 0)
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = timeoutValue;
        }

        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        foreach (var param in parameters)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(param);
        }

        _databaseHelper.OpenConnection(command);
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        _databaseHelper.CloseConnection(command);
    }

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: This depends entirely on what `_databaseHelper.CloseConnection()` does. The use of `Database.Connection` is also suspect - generally you would not want to `Dispose()` of something that is owned elsewhere. If `Database.Connection` is indeed returning a new connection instance each time, I'd switch it to a `GetConnection()` method.

Comment: @dahlbyk why would it depend on closeconnection? what if there is an exception right before this line?

Comment: var sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)Database.Connection; if this code return new connection I think the problem not will be

Comment: @dahlbyk Database.Connection is DbContext.Connection

Answer (score 2):

well you don't open a new connection here, so it wont get disposed anyway and thats not the deal.

`SqlCommand` will ge closed properly in any case, because you're using `using` construction. However, if this line, for example `var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);` will throw exception, `_databaseHelper.CloseConnection(command);` obviously wont be called

Answer (score 1):

> Does *sqlConnection* get properly disposed?

No. `_databaseHelper.CloseConnection(command)` implies that it might include a `command.Connection.Close()` call, which is equivalent to calling `Dispose()`, but this would not be described as "properly" because it's not in a `finally` block.